# is it good idea to use try catch blocks in test methods c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest

I have a test method like this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var smthing= new doSmthing();
        smthing.doSomefunction("Test Service","Test Operation");

       // do something next
       var 2ndsmthing = do2ndSmthing();
       2ndsmthing.do2ndSomeThing("Test","Method")
    }
```

believe me these two functions or calls needs to be under same test method how can i prevent the test from stopping if something goes wrong while calling first method? i.e while calling doSmthing() I heard that its a bad idea to use Try...Catch blocks in test method. How can i solve this?

Any idea really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want your test to recover from something you didn't anticipate ("something went wrong")?  (also, run your code through a compiler before posting to SO -- it's self-evident you did not do this)

Comment: its because second method is recording what's happening in the first method. so its important for me to go to 2nd method. if its a failure i need to go there with failure result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect and want to test for an exception, you can use the ExpectedException attribute on your test method.

If you want to "swallow" the exception thrown by the first two lines, you would have to try/catch it.  As with any exception handling, you should catch the most specific exception you can.

In 15 years, several of which were spent on TDD projects, I have never personally seen a test that swallows an exception so that some other code can run.

You *should* split them in to two tests. [/soapbox]

Comment: ya i see what you mean but its not actually swallowing the exceptions. It recording them.